# Strange behavior with "map(range ...)"

Tags: vimscript, command-line, functions

I'm trying to get into more advanced features of vimscript, so I'm trying to figure out how to use the `map` function, so I thought I'd write a function that returns every character with ASCII values between two numbers. For example,

```
CharRange(65, 90)
```

would give

> ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

So I tried this:

```
echo map(range(65, 90), function('nr2char'))
```

But I got some very strange results. Instead of giving ASCII 65-90, it gave ASCII 1-25.

```
^A ^B ^C ^D ^E ^F ^G ^H ^K ^L ^M ^N ^O ^P ^Q ^R ^S ^T ^U ^V ^W ^X ^Y
```

(of course it gave unprintables rather than the carets followed by letters)

After this didn't work, I tried some other ways, but none of them worked right. For example, a lambda:

```
echo join(map(range(50, 100), {arg1 -> nr2char(arg1)}))
```

This gives the exact same results. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at [`:h map`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#map%28%29):

```
map({expr1}, {expr2})                                   map()
                {expr1} must be a List or a Dictionary.
                Replace each item in {expr1} with the result of evaluating
                {expr2}.  {expr2} must be a string or Funcref.             
...
                If {expr2} is a Funcref it is called with two arguments:
                        1. The key or the index of the current item.
                        2. the value of the current item.
```

Therefore, what `map` does for `65` in this case actually call `nr2char(0, 65)`, and for [`nr2char`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#nr2char%28%29):

```
nr2char({expr}[, {utf8}])                               nr2char()
                Return a string with a single character, which has the number
                value {expr}.  ...
               When {utf8} is omitted or zero, the current 'encoding' is used.
                Example for "utf-8": 
                        nr2char(300)            returns I with bow character
               With {utf8} set to 1, always return utf-8 characters.
```

So, the `65` is pretty much ignored, and you get the U+0 character:

```
['', '^A', '^B', '^C', '^D', '^E', '^F', '^G', '^H', '  ', '
', '^N', '^O', '^P', '^Q', '^R', '^S', '^T', '^U', '^V', '^W', '^X', '^Y']
```

See [`man 7 ascii`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man7/ascii.7.html).

The help does have an example of this problem, but it's in [`:h lambda`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#lambda):

```
Examples for using a lambda expression with sort(), map() and filter(): 
    :echo map([1, 2, 3], {idx, val -> val + 1})
   [2, 3, 4] 
    :echo sort([3,7,2,1,4], {a, b -> a - b})
   [1, 2, 3, 4, 7]
```

The first example shows that `map` passes two arguments, and the second is the actual value.

Comment: I get what the problem is but I can't figure how to solve it?

Comment: @statox OP knows how to use lambdas, so I figured it'd be a quick step from this to one solution: `map(range(65, 90),  {k, v -> nr2char(v)})`. Or, using the String version of `map`: `map(range(65, 90), 'nr2char(v:val)')`.

Comment: I was trying to use `v:val` with no success. Thanks for your answer!